# Textblob tweets : TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> , rows are lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, textblob

**Defining a function to get sentiment out of tweets:** (written by me)

```
def get_tweet_sentiment(tweet): 
    '''Utility function to classify sentiment of passed tweet using textblob's sentiment method'''
    # create TextBlob object of passed tweet text 
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet) 
    
    # set sentiment 
    if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
        return 'positive'
    elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0: 
        return 'neutral'
    else: 
        return 'negative'
```

**Calling function to get sentiment:**

```
from textblob import TextBlob 
get_tweet_sentiment(df['tweet_content'])
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

**My df is of the type below:'**

```
tweet_content                   Col2    Col3
[Hi, I , really, like , you]    89      90
[You, are , too , sweet]       777      990   and so on. There are 30,000 such rows.
```

Please help how to either change the function or the way to call the function

Comment: Maybe you got list as input so make string from list would help? Something ike: `get_tweet_sentiment(' '.join(df['tweet_content'].values.tolist()))`

Comment: Hi, no i got list after tokenisation.....So cant this be done even if my list remains the way it is..Actually the list structure is needed for making word cloud

Comment: `get_tweet_sentiment()` expect that `text` is string, not a list. And you got `pd.Series()` as input

Comment: Your code gives this error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

Comment: Ya so please suggest how to edit the function (get_tweet_sentiment is written by me, so how to change either the function or way to call)

Comment: Try `df['tweet content'].apply(lambda x: get_tweet_sentiment(x), axis = 1)`. This would apply the function to every row of that column.

Comment: @formicaman, function required string and each cell is list, so suggest tweak a bit: `df['tweet content'].apply(lambda x: get_tweet_sentiment(' '.join(x)), axis = 1)`

Comment: `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'` for both codes got this error

Comment: without axis=1, @OYisiyl your code is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your problem was be that function `get_tweet_sentiment()` required `string` as input, and you tried to pass `pd.Series()` as input. So the solution is using `df.apply()` with `lambda`, which simply run `get_tweet_sentiment()` at each row. But again, each cell in `df['tweet_content']` column is a list, which contains each word as a separate `string` element. To make thing works, you can use `' '.join(x)` - which create from list `['Hi', 'I', 'really', 'like', 'you']` string `Hi I really like you` - and this you could pass to function.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd   
def get_tweet_sentiment(text):
  print(text)
  return text

df = pd.DataFrame([[['Hi', 'Bird']], [['Hello', 'Bear']]])
df.columns = ['tweet_content']
print(df.head())
df['tweet_content'].apply(lambda x: get_tweet_sentiment(' '.join(x)))
```

Output:

```
   tweet_content
0     [Hi, Bird]
1  [Hello, Bear]
Hi Bird
Hello Bear
```